# Can't insert into mysql database in windows 7. Program written in java using macintosh

Tags: java, mysql, macos, windows-7

I had written a java program in eclipse for macintosh and my data is in a MySQL database. When packing it to a runnable jar file it works perfect in the macintosh. It inserts data, loads data and updates data from the databases, but when running the runnable jar in windows 7 it loads data, updates data but doesn't insert data to the databases. i don't have a developer program on the windows machine to look for messages caught by the console. And I don't know what else can i do for making it work (I've been developing this program 10 months ago and now i feel so frustrated). Anyone Help Me, please.

Comment: Why don't you just get a developer program on the Windows box?

Comment: Are you using the same MySql account (login) from both boxes?

Comment: Yes, i'm using the same login info.

Comment: Are there freeware developer programs that can read the runnable jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a developer environment to get the error messages. Change your code on your macintosh to dump the error messages to console or a log file and execute on windows console.

Get error messages and let us try to do something valuable to solve the problem.

Comment: In the code, the part that inserts into the databases catches the exception with:  catch (SQLException e) {
    
    e.printStackTrace();
   } where is supposed to be written in the windows box?  . Thank you for your answer and i apologize for been new for these forums.

Comment: Hello Mr. Serkan. I didn't know i could look the program console from windows 7 command line. After some research i realize the way to execute jar from command line and i could see was the error was and solve it. The problem was related to a "." part of the locale format. Thanks to you i could solve it. Thank you very much. Couldn't vote you up because i don't have the reputation. Thank you.

Comment: It is better to catch the Exception or Throwable rather then SQLException. If there is no stack trace on the console, it is probably due to a non-sql exception.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Serkan. for your answer. i'm new with java and still don't distinguish the difference between them. But i will count with that too.